# Best way to setup global variables in oop?

Tags: php, oop

I am having a hard time finding an answer to this, I am sure it's there in front of me but I cant put it together.

```
    //Global Variables
    global $GLOBAL;
    $GLOBAL['myPluginPath'] = dirname( __FILE__ );


    //Main Object   
    class My_Class {

            public function __construct() {

                    // Initialize Settings
                    require_once $GLOBAL['myPluginPath'] . '/settings.php';
                    $My_Settings = new My_Settings();

            } 
     }
```

I want to use a variable so my code feels more organized, I feel I can read my code better when paths are defined this way and it makes it easier to change the variables so that it applys throughout the whole code if needed.

I can get the variables to work by writing this inside my methods.

```
    public function WhatEverFunc() {
        global $GLOBAL
        require_once $GLOBAL['myPluginPath'] . '/settings.php'; 
   }
```

The primary question here, I am wondering if this is bad practice, if not is there a better way then having to define `global $GLOBAL` inside each method. If however it is bad practice can you show me good practice?

There is a one other thing I am really curious about. Inside the main `__construct` you see I don't use `global $GLOBAL` because it works without it, but inside that `require_once` file is another class which has methods that must use `global $GLOBAL` inside of them. Hope someone can explain that.

Some are saying this is bad practice, I think. I read there is a singleton pattern(bad practice) and a global pattern. Not sure what I did above constitutes, I am just a little lost from what I should do here with what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: OOP and Global don't really go well together.

Comment: Ok, definitely will always note that @Jack, but using OOP isnt there a good way to define things for reuse? like plugin version and file paths.. so that if I need to change the version I only do it once?

Comment: Thanks for the keywords there, ill definitely look those up and figure out what they are. I want to fully understand OOP, I am sure I will use this structure to build my own interfaces and web apps later on. Right now I am just extending wordpress with a plugin. and just need a good structure to setup my actual plugins function which consists of form data.

Comment: Also, you may just want to consider [constants](http://php.net/constants) while you're at it; I think that's arguably a cleaner approach than global state.

Comment: Reading up on it now, and it looks like a good approach as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)? You don't even need to use `global` keyword.

> > The primary question here, I am wondering if this is bad practice

Well, I believe most people would say having a global state is bad practice because it is harder to manage or doing unit test. Most people would suggest you to use "dependency injection" which instead of depend on global state, you need to inject what the class need directly.

Comment: Reason for not using `$GLOBALS` is I saw it in someone elses code, but grew fond of it, didn't want the same name lol.. I saw a few mentions to `$GLOBALS` elsewhere and figured it was universal, glad you confirmed and pointed it out..

Comment: Okay I get that, but what if the global variables were just common PHP syntax like `dirname` and plugin paths etc.. as well as plugin version numbers...

Comment: Well, having global variable mixing with OOP is harder to manage because if your code is getting larger and larger, how do you know if you change a global variable value or decide to delete it, which object will awfully got affected by it.

Comment: I switched to `$GLOBALS` and that worked without having to define `global $var` that makes sense. Well I can see why using a global variable for anything else would result in bad practice, I could understand why they stress not to use it, but really my use for the global is just for plugin version and file path.. So it works well with `$GLOBALS` and I am sticking with it.. I like it, and as long as it doesnt cause any issues in my case which I dont see that it will, I am going to use it..

Answer (score 9):

An object really should have everything needed for it to perform any function it is designed to. If not, the data should be passed via a param to it.

Part of the whole point of objects versus procedural code is that objects can be re-used over and over and in many places.

Lets use this example of why using Globals and OOP is a bad idea:

Lets say you have a great front-end bit of code, and you write it all through objects. Sometime down the track, you need to create additional reporting on the data in your site. You start to code and realize that you can re-use your classes from the front to achieve almost everything you need - but alas your code contains numerous references to globals that are only visible in the front end if called from a certain script.

That's basically just made your objects rather un-reusable.

Although it's probably not the best practise, but I often write a quick class that grabs a hold of various `$GET`, `$_POST` and other variables which might be considered "Globals" such as URL params and the like, then in my code, I either pass this information directly to the objects/functions as needed or indeed pass the entire object (rarely).

Using this approach, I am always perfectly ready to re-use objects knowing EXACTLY what they need to function as they are all required in params.

Comment: Wow I appreciate this answer, I like the example, examples are always good. I still have much more experimenting with OOP to fully understand reusing objects etc. I am building a plugin, and its primarily an HTML form and javascript. The use of the OOP structure is to setup the plugin, so its not very much code, playing with OOP I really like the structure, I feel very organized. I cant see using the global variables the way I am using them causing any issue of any sort. If I do however come across an issue, Ill know exactly what your'e talking about.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Although PHP allows us to write some very very "interesting" code, it's not always a good idea to do so. If you are writing code to be the best it can be, take the extra time and make the object completely stand-alone. It should function anywhere by someone including the class file and then just saying `$var=new yourObject();`

Comment: Oh THANKS.. this actually kind of hit me on the head.. OMG so I understand `$var=new yourObject()` creates a new instance of the object which is cool! If I tried using this new instance those global variables that were defined inside the object wouldnt work outside the object?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry I would assume so (Not really ever done that) but why not just write a function to return the data - or an array of data as the `return` rather than making it into a global? This way you can use a `$var=$YourObject->OutputData();` and BAM, you have the data in your script where you need it.

Comment: The thing is following this boilerplate https://github.com/fyaconiello/wp_plugin_template all my code is doing is creating methods then hooking those into wordpress `hook` functions which passes into the constructor.. at least this is my interpretation of whats going on.. I literally learned what OOP is 2 days ago and studied all day for the past two days.. So I know what I know based on the structure of the boilerplate.. So I am not trying to pass data, I am just creating a structure to hook my form into wordpress. I save data into the wordpress db with a method that is hooked into construct

Comment: Using the `$GLOBALS` works fine now. I hope I dont run into any issues but if I do, then I will understand what you are talking about more. Ill eventually learn my lesson, most likely in bigger projects, but I am just using globals to define plugin version and, paths...

Answer (score 3):

From your code it seems that you're just looking for a way to resolve your class names into file names. For that purpose it's better to use [auto loaders](http://php.net/autoload). It takes the formality of how your classes map to file names away from the bulk of your code so that you can concentrate on *actual* development.

Organizing your plugins can be done by using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Second, in most cases you don't want to instantiate classes inside the constructor because it leads to coupling, and too much coupling can stifle your project later; instead, inject the dependency:

```
class My_Class 
{
    private $settings;

    public function __construct(My_Settings $settings) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    } 
}
```

To call it:

```
$c = new My_Class(new My_Settings());
```

Comment: Hmm this is interesting, It's new and since you do have high rep I assume this is a fantastic way to go about it... I did follow a few tuts that operate according to your code.. but the structure of my code comes from a boilerplate that wordpress linked to in their own codex. I didnt provide full code, so the above may threw you off to what I am trying to accomplish. but essentially the code above is the main class of my plugin which the `require_once` contains other branches of my plugin which contains classes of their own.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry, I suggest you take Jack's advice and try using auto loaders with a blank PHP project to see how it works, then, you can decide whether to use it or not with your real project.

Comment: I toyed with something like this before, but I am not sure I can wrap it in with how I have structured my project? I see he passes in `My_Settings` inside the constructor, but how is he going to include the file.. I am using this boilerplate, and the wordpress codex links to it.. https://github.com/fyaconiello/wp_plugin_template I understand how the author sets everthing up very well, like the back of my hand, I studied this code very much.. I dont understand how I can use that method in accordance with @Jack's method?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry If you organize plugins in a namespace, autoloading can take care of most of your issues here.

Answer (score -3):

Use this example to solve your problem

The global keyword doesn't work the way you think it does. It does not make a variable have global scope. All it does is specify to the function that you call it in that you want to use the variable in the outer scope.

For example:

```
$a="test";

function something() {
    global $a;
    echo $a;  //Outputs: test
}
```

If you want to make a variable global so that it can be accessed from within a class, you need to use the $GLOBALS superglobal.